# call return inside GCC compound statement expressions

Tags: gcc, expression

Can I safely use return inside GCC compound statement expressions ?

For example I define macro

```
#define CHECK_FUNC_RESULT(func)    \
({                                 \
   int result = func();            \
   if (!result) return;            \
   result;                         \
})
```

and use it somewhere in code in such way:

```
int function1() 
{
   if (some_condition) 
     return 0;
   ...
   return 1; 
}

void function2()
{
   if(CHECK_FUNC_RESULT(function1)) {
      ... to do something
   }
}
```

Can I expect returning from function2 (on some_condition == true) without any undefined behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

It should work, but your if() statement will only be processed if function1 returns 1 (in your example: never). This looks like a dangerous construction, as an else would never be executed.

Comment: Please, can you be more specific ?

Comment: if(CHECK_FUNC_RESULT(function1)) {
      ... to do something
   } else { 
... do something else 
   }

In this case, the else will not be executed. Without looking at the macro definition, this is not obvious.

Otherwise, I can't find any reference pointing to an undefined behaviour when there is a return statement within the if condition. So it should work as you intend it to work, but if someone else looks at the code it can be confusing.

Comment: But what about the topic of the question ? Is this undefined behavior or no ?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this will not result in undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way to achieve what you want, and you can also pass any number of arguments to func (in this example 3 args):

```
#define RET_IF_ZERO(func, args) \
do {                            \
    int result = func args;     \
    if (!result)                \
        return;                 \
} while (0)
```

Example of usage:

```
void function1(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
{
    if (some_condition) 
        return 0;
    ...
    return 1;
}

void function2()
{
   RET_IF_ZERO(function1, (arg1, arg2, arg3)));

   ... do to something
}
```

Comment: Your answer does not correspond with topic of question